# XML/XSLT in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml, internet-explorer, xslt

I've been looking into examples of using XML and XSLT in JavaScript and I don't understand the differences between the different options in IE:

- Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0
- Msxml2.DOMDocument.3.0
- Microsoft.XMLHTTP
- Microsoft.XMLDom

So when using the approach:

```
var xml = new ActiveXObject("Xxxxxxx");
```

With xxxxxx being one of the above variations.

Which should I use?  What is the difference between them?

Comment: You might want to take a look at here: http://ajaxpatterns.org/XMLHttpRequest_Call

Comment: Thanks @benqus - so that link seems to point at new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); as being the one to use. But what is the story behind the others, do they perform the same function or do they have alternative uses?

Comment: Maybe they have but I guess in earlier versions of the internet. =) I might be wrong, and those are really IE and Microsoft specific stuff, but the general approach is to use the one mentioned in the link. That's cool for text and xml also. =)

Comment: Yeah the non-Microsoft browser approach is much more simple, but this has me a bit perplexed in terms of covering older versions of IE. Thanks for the info I'm happy with the xmlhttp approach!

Comment: By the way, why aren't you using JSON? Way much simple and you can achieve the same with less data sent/received. Might be handy on mobile devices... =)

Comment: Just learning the basics before I move on to anything more complex, I'll make sure I check out JSON though as I have heard it is a lot more lightweight than XML. Trying not to skip over anything in my learning like I've done in the past haha

Comment: I totally understand you. =) I have done the same. =) One good advice with IT: always, always read the whole page of the documentations! =D It helps a lot and when you get to answer questions over here you will know what you are talking about! =) Not only droid answers and stuff. =)
But still, JSON is more widely used when it comes to webapplications. =) And you'll also have some sight on JavaScript's OOP stuff. =) Let me know if you get stuck somewhere with front-end stuff. =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Microsoft's COM based XML software package is called MSXML and exists in different versions that can co-exist on a Windows system. All currently supported Microsoft OS versions respectively latest supported service packs of Microsoft OS come with MSXML 3 and MSXML 6. The program ids you pass in to `ActiveXObject` in JScript are documented for MSXML 3 here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms766426%28v=vs.85%29 and for MSXML 6 here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms764622%28v=vs.85%29. As you can see, somehow confusingly the program ids start with 'MSXML2' and the MSXML version is appended at the end so an MSXML 3.0 DOM document has the program id `MSXML2.DOMDocument.3.0` and an MSXML 6.0 DOM document the program id `Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0`.

Program ids starting with `Microsoft.` are legacy program ids introduced with older MSXML versions, you shouldn't need them these days where MSXML 3 and MSXML 6 are part of the OS or latest service on any supported OS.

As for which version to choose of MSXML 3 or 6, that depends partly on what you want to do; the main difference between MSXML 3 and MSXML 6 is that MSXML 6 has a parser supporting validation against a schema or a schema set while MSXML 3 only supports DTD based validation. MSXML 6 by default also has some tighter security related settings you need to be aware of, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754611%28v=vs.85%29.

As your post also mentions XSLT, both MSXML 3 and 6 support XSLT and XPath 1.0 so in terms of standard compliance you can choose either of them, in terms of performance you might find that MSXML 6 performs better.